# SQL Server 2008 - Return records in chronological order, given a separation factor

Tags: sql-server, index

This question was originally posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492149/return-records-in-chronological-order-given-a-separation-factor and re-posted on this forum given a user's advice.

I have a massive table in SQL Server 2008, it contains the position reported by technicians every minute. I need to report on this table but in order to control the amount of records that are displayed in the report both a time and distance separation factors need to be taken into account.

So, a query may look like : "Return all records with no less than 5 minutes and/or 300 feet between them".

The time part is done, but I'm having a hard time with the distance factor. I have the latitude and longitude for each point, and I have no problem if I need to include a SQL Server 2008 spatial UDT in order to resolve the problem.

Things I have considered:

- Bring the records by the time factor, and apply the separation constrain in the client by calculating the distance between adjacent points and discard those which falls inside the the factor. (the easiest, but it must be the one consuming more resources).
- Keep the last record per technician in a cache, pre-calculate the distance between the record and its predecessor, and resolve the constrain in the client. (should consume less resources than 1) since the distance is pre-calculated, however and since the table is BIG It will increase the size of the dataset, not sure if the space is worth the processing savings).
- Use the spatial functions in SQL Server 2008, but honestly I had been reading and I couldn't find anything that helps me resolve this type of requirement. Any GIS expert??

I would like to go with the best option possible (maybe not listed above?) and IMO should be the one using the SQL Server features most efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to SQL 2008, the most common solution was to use a UDF to calculate the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere. [The Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is probably the most commonly used method.

Of course the Earth is not actually a perfect sphere, but this was considered "good enough" for most uses.

In SQL 2008, as you anticipated, such calculations are simplified and made more accurate by the introduction of the Geography and Geometry data types. Here's a brief sample of how you can use them to simplify distance calculations.

```
DECLARE @locations TABLE(locname VARCHAR(100), coord geography)
DECLARE @loc1 geography
DECLARE @loc2 geography


INSERT INTO @locations 
VALUES('HOME', geography::Point(-81.810194, 41.478156, 4326))   --Note: Lat, Long, SRID
                                                                --The 4326 is the SRID (spatial reference id) used by SQL as 
                                                                --a reference to the WGS 84 Standard. This is the same reference
                                                                --used by the GPS system
INSERT INTO @locations 
VALUES('WORK', geography::Point(-81.687771, 41.498227, 4326))

SELECT * FROM @locations

SELECT @loc1 = coord FROM @locations WHERE locname = 'HOME'
SELECT @loc2 = coord FROM @locations WHERE locname = 'WORK'

SELECT @loc1.STDistance(@loc2) * 3.2808399  --STDistance is in meters so we multiply to convert to feet 

SELECT @loc1.STIntersects(@loc2.STBuffer(300 / 3.2808399)) as isWithin300Ft  --This formula returns True when the point @loc1 intersects with the 300ft buffer zone around @loc2
```

The SRID is the key to the improved accuracy. The [WGS 84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) specification to which it refers includes a standardized coordinate system and a reference ellipsoid.  In other words, it accounts for the non-spherical nature of the Earth, giving better results than a pure spherical Great Circle calculation.

If GIS accuracy is important to your work, this is the simplest way to implement it in SQL 2008.

Comment: Jonathan, while this is great to calculate the distance between 2 points my problem actually is how to (_given a set of points_) extract only those that are above certain distance threshold, or (_maybe the same_) consider them a cluster so X points near each other below the threshold can be considered a single point. <br /><br /> 
**Ideally** I want to do this w/o having to iterate through the entire collection; and I was hoping to find a spatial function that does that for me.

Comment: Finding points within a threshold is quite simple. I added an additional line to the code block to demonstrate how you can test for the intersection of a point with a buffer around another point. If you need to do nearest-neighbor clustering that is also feasible, but more complex and more computationally expensive.

Comment: Jonathan, sorry I'm not a GIS guy so I'm not 100% familiar with the terms.

Comment: Let's say you started walking and turn on an app that reports your location every minute. Let's say that at certain speed you are reporting your position every 100 feet, but for the type of analysis I need to do at the end of the day, I'm just interested in your position every 500 feet. If you move at a constant speed (lets assume so for simplicity) that means I need to report every 4 points.

Comment: So, the whole deal is not about 2 points, but about how to return the number of records given the threshold fir the whole set w/o having to loop through all records _at least not in the client or by using a SQL cursor_.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you are solving for this: Sample all points within a given 5-minute period. If all of them cluster within 300ft of each other, treat one of the points as a representative pt and discard the rest. If not all of them cluster within 300ft, then create 2 clusters and choose 2 representative pts. If that doesn't cover all pts, 3 clusters, etc. i.e. you are trying to reduce the number of nodes in the path while still having the resulting path be a close fit to the actual path?

Comment: Correct, and when I think in the problem looping comes naturally and I'm trying to avoid it given the size of the dataset.  
This feature will give the supervisor the ability to look how technicians move in certain periods of time, with certain threshold so he can discard those points close enough (open criteria) as to be considered stationary.